# Random string for forgotten password is correct in MySQL but doesn't work in form

Tags: php

I wasn't sure how to search for the issue I'm experiencing.

The code works properly to produce a randomly generated, encrypted password, but the password does not work when submitting the HTML form. I verified the password through the SQL query to make sure it was valid and it was.

In response to the user below, here's the query I used:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='test@test.com' AND password=MD5('03884d917f');
```

03884d917f is the password that was generated. I queried the test@test.com account correctly with it.

To be more concise: the generated password changes properly in MySQL, but when submitted on the front-end I can't log in using it.

I don't think any additional code is required, the only bit that would be of use is config.php which only deals in connecting the database and establishing variables for the mail functions.

2 down-votes without actual input on how I could change the post to accomodate people. I tried to narrow down my problem, I'm not sure how else to explain it. Anyone want to respond with something of substance?

PHP:

```
    <?php
    require_once('config.php');
    mysql_select_db($database,$dbhandle);
    include_once('includes/header.inc.php');
    include_once('includes/navigation.inc.php');

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
    {

    $email = $_POST['remail'];
    $pattern = '/^[^@]+@[^\s\r\n\'";,@%]+$/';
    if (!preg_match($pattern, trim($email))) {
      $error[] = 'Please enter a valid email address';
    } 

    $check = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = '$email'")or
    die(mysql_error());
    $check2 = mysql_num_rows($check);

    if ($check2 == 0) {
    $error[] = 'Sorry, we cannot find your account details please try another email address.';
    }

    if (!$error) {

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = '$email' ")or die         (mysql_error());
    $r = mysql_fetch_object($query);

    $password = substr(uniqid(rand(),1),3,10);
    $pass = md5($password); //encrypted version for database entry

    $to = "$email";
    $subject = "Account Details Recovery";
    $body = "Hi $r->email, \n\n you or someone else have requested your account details. \n\n Here is your account information please keep this as you may need this at a later stage. \n\nYour email is $r->email \n\n your password is $password \n\n Your password has been reset please login and change your password to something more rememberable.\n\n Regards Site Admin";
    $additionalheaders = "From: admin@cenz.cz";
    $additionalheaders .= "Reply-To: admin@cenz.cz";
    mail($to, $subject, $body, $additionalheaders);

    //update database
    $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET password='$pass' WHERE email = '$email'")or die (mysql_error());
    $rsent = true;


    }
    }

    if (!empty($error))
    {
    $i = 0;
    while ($i < count($error)){
    echo "<div class=\"msg-error\">".$error[$i]."</div>";
    $i ++;}
    }


    if ($rsent == true){
echo "<p align='center'>You have been sent an email with your account details to $email</p>\n";
} else {
echo "<h2>Reset Password</h2><p align='center'>Please enter your e-mail address. You will receive a new password via e-mail.</p>\n";
}

    ?>

    <form class="box login" action="" method="post">
    <fieldset class="boxBody">
    <label for="remail">Email Address: </label>
    <input type="text" name="remail" size="50" maxlength="255" tabindex="1" />
    </fieldset>
    <footer>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Reset Password" class="btnLogin" tabindex="2">
    </footer>
    </form>
    <?php include_once('includes/footer.inc.php'); ?>
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like this code is the problem. It must be in the scrip that actually verifies the correct password (which you haven't included, right?).  What sql query do you use to check for a valid password?

Comment: Thanks for your response. The query I used was:
SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='test@test.com' AND password=MD5('03884d917f');

Comment: This post is too long but doesn't provide the actual code that is needed to judge the problem. Please rewrite your question to be more concise and provide the important information instead of all the other stuff.

Comment: I'm sorry, Markus. I don't know how to explain the issue. The script works to generate a random password. If I try to use it in the form, the password doesn't work. I queried it to check that the password I was provided is the one being stored in the database and it was. So the problem is why did the password change in the database but not work in the front-end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

md5() generates the hash according to the character encoding.

If table encoding is utf-8, for example, encode it like this:

```
$pass = md5(utf8_encode($password));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Felipe! I tried your solution, but I'm still having this issue.

Comment: It seems the problem has to do with the character encoding, anyway. I think the way it should be read is something like this **...AND MD5('password') LIKE '{03884d917f}'"**, but I have not tested. Check the examples in the PHP manual

Comment: Thanks for your replies, Felipe. It was based off them that I decided to encrypt the password differently. I'll reply with my fixed code in an answer. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to encrypt differently. The problem had something to do with encrypting via MD5. Instead I used sha256 encryption.

Here's the code I used:

```
    function HashPassword($input)
    {
    random salt
    $salt = bin2hex(mcrypt_create_iv(32, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)); 
    $hash = hash("sha256", $salt . $input); 
    $final = $salt . $hash; 
    return $final;
    }
    $password = substr(uniqid(rand(),1),3,10);
    $pass = (HashPassword($password));
```